# Understands why question got closed, still not sure how to rephrase

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/915728/free-or-almost-free-tool-for-receiving-wcf-calls-with-values) and it got put on hold with the motivation that it's asking for a service/software which quickly get outdated etc. I'm perfectly fine with the action taken and I do understand the explanation.

My problem is that I still need to ask that question and I'd need some help rephrasing it to better meet the requirements. Let me explain what **kind of pointer** I'm looking for.

Example 1
If I'm looking for a simple, free text editor, the de facto industry standard (or at least a very commonly found software since years back) is **Notepad++**. That'd be the answer I'd find useful and helpful. (Possibly a mention of Sublime might be in place too.)

Example 2
If I'm looking for a useful, free image editor, the first choice of many people (including blogs with well-known and reliable names) is **Paint.NET**. That's the answer that satisfies the conditions. (Even Gimp might be an alternative.)

So, I wonder how I should rephrase my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/915728/free-or-almost-free-tool-for-receiving-wcf-calls-with-values) so that:

1. it meets the site's requirements

but also

2. points to something "defaulty" or "commonish"

i.e. how to ask so that the answer would be *Notepad++* or *Paint.NET* but in the case with a web service that receives simple chunks of data and presents these in a rudimentary web GUI?

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 2):

Its not very clear what you're looking for. Web services are off topic on SU anyway, and on SR.

Chat's probably a good place to air this sort of thing - someone might suggest [yahoo pipes](https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)... or the shiny run your own one some news agency threw up and someone on chat might remember the name.

Course this works better for chat regulars ;p

Comment: Too bad... I was hoping for some utility, like *Assembla* is for for a quick and online SVN available for free... It's more of a utility I'm looking for than an actual web service. Although it **will** be using a web service, of course.

Comment: Ahh, the first step is clarifying your question. since I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Which question are you referring to? The original post or the one at Meta? I'm totally up for clarifying what I mean but at the moment I can't see which part that's vague or unspecific. I've tried to explain a parallel issue for a text and image editor (i.e. NP++ and Paint.NET). So the question is, **kind of**, "*how should I ask to get the answer 'NP++'*". Then, I can apply the same pattern and make it about the data receiver/viewer I'm looking for. If there are any to be found.

Comment: There isn't a Stackexchange where a question asking for a web service would be on topic.  So even simply asking about a reciver/viewer wouldn't be on topic on a SE website.